# conjugating before and after a くれ

Tags: sentence

What's the difference between:

笑わないでくれ

笑ってくれないで

Answer (score 4, accepted):

～ないでくれる means "(someone) does me the favor of not doing (something)."
～てくれない means "(someone) doesn't do me the favor of doing (something)."

Compare:

笑わないでくれる -- "does me the favor of not laughing"
You want someone not to laugh, and they don't laugh.
vs
笑ってくれない -- "doesn't do me the favor of laughing"
You want someone to laugh, but they don't laugh.

---

「笑わないでくれ。」 would mean "(Please) don't laugh."
(くれ is the imperative form of くれる.)

You could use 「笑ってくれないで...」 to mean "(I want someone to laugh, but) they don't laugh, and..."
(ないで is one of the continuative forms of ない.)

<sub>「笑わ**ないで**。」 can mean "(Please) don't laugh." but 「笑って**くれないで**」 doesn't mean that.</sub>

Comment: So ～てくれないで can't mean "don't do ~ for me!"? As in, "I don't want your favour of ~!"

Comment: 普通は「～てくれないで。」って言わないですね。「～てくれないでください。」って言わないから。（「～してくれなくていいよ」とか「～してほしくない」「～してもらいたくない」とかかな・・）

Comment: ありがとうございました。勉強になりました。